# DATEADD and @Var in SQL Update Command

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

I want to update a `time(0)` column with the following command. (`SQLDataSource` in VS 2015)

```
UPDATE       tb_reported
SET                Time = DATEADD(Hour, @Quantity, Time)
WHERE        (EmpShort = @EmpShort) AND (Date = @Date) AND (Time > @Time)
```

When i test the command (run query) it asks me for the values of the 4 parameters. for `@Quantity` i use e.g. "2" to add 2 hours. Then i click "OK" and get an error message regarding the format of the `@Quantity` parameter:

> "Error Message: parameter value could not be converted from Decimal to TimeSpan"

When i use e.g. "2" instead of `@Quantity` the update runs without problems.

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: How did you declare the @Quantity parameter?

Comment: Is this an in-line sql statement?

Comment: This kind of errors are occurs when there were difference between timezone locale.. you must put same kind of date format to `@Date` as per your locale like `dd/MM/yyyy` or others.

Comment: what type did you assign when declaring @Quantity?

Comment: Are you sure you have thought this through?  What if you try to add three hours to 22:00?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: i use a SQL Server 2014

Comment: @DanBracuk - this is not possible by design of the input

Comment: @Felix this is in Visual Studio 2015 - SQLDataSource - UpdateQuery

Answer (score 0):

First try declaring `@Quantity` or lets say `@Time`

```
DECLARE @Time BIGINT();
@Time = DATEADD(Hour, '2', Time);
```

New SQL:

```
UPDATE tb_reported
SET    Time = @Time
WHERE  (EmpShort = @EmpShort) 
       AND (Date = @Date) 
       AND (Time > @Time)
```

Comment: I can't edit my answer but change this line `@Time = DATEADD(Hour, '2', Time);` to `SELECT @Time = DATEADD(Hour, '2', Time);`

Comment: I don't think this is the OP's issue.  Sounds like there's an issue with the parameter declaration

Comment: i tried to switch the "Type"-property of the parameter from "Empty" to any other value but the error message still says "decimal" to "timespan"